# How can I change constraint of height with button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change my calendar height's constraint 124 to zero when calendar button is clicked how can I do that? I want to use button statement but I couldn't at objective c. Thanks.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *calendarButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightOfCalendar;`

- (IBAction)calendarAction:(id)sender {

}
```

Comment: -(IBAction)calendarAction:(id)sender {
heightOfCalendar.constant = 0;
}

Comment: not working man.

Comment: gives me the same error.

Comment: add layoutIfNeeded also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in your IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)calendarAction:(id)sender {
    self.heightOfCalendar.constant = 0;
}
```

Also make sure you have your IBAction connection set properly.

And I see a ` symbol at the end of the following statement:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightOfCalendar;`
```

Answer (score 1):

> > you need to set constant property

```
heightOfCalendar.constant = requiredheight
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Do like this to change size on each tap

```
- (IBAction)calendarAction:(id)sender {
      sender.selected = !sender.selected;
      heightOfCalendar.constant = (sender.selected)?0:124; 
}
```

Comment: the error that, Property 'selected' not found on object type '_strong id', occurred. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with an animation will looks good

```
(IBAction)calendarAction:(id)sender {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{

                           heightOfCalendar.constant =0;
                             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

                         }];
}
```